# Get model of custom category

Tags: magento

We have added in our categories trees some attributes to the categories

[image]

Its posible to make a foreach `Mage::getModel(custom categories)` to get all the value of the custom categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access those attributes but you will need to load the category first. Now just getting the custom attributes might be a little harder.

```
$cateogry = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load('category here');
//this could get you all attributes
$attributes = $category->getAttributes();
//this would get you just the two attributes that look custom above
$customAttributes = array(
'latitude' => $category->getLatitude(),
'longitude' =>$category->getLongitude(),
);
```

I hope this helps!